# flash drive no longer works after making it Ubuntu bootable using Rufus

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb, usb-flash-drive, rufus

Yesterday I made my flash drive **Ubuntu bootable using Rufus**. The operation of making it bootable was successful but when I ejected the flash drive from that computer it stopped working. It is not showing up in the **Boot Menu** or **My Computer** or **Disk Management** in any computer.

I can only see the flash drive in the **Device Manager** as **Unknown USB Device(Device Descriptor Request Failed)**.

Is there any way to fix my flash drive?

Comment: Try it in another computer.  Does it behave the same way?

Comment: Do you have a Windows computer available? You could try using 'Diskpart' to delete and reformat.

Comment: Tried in 3 computers all running Windows 10. Diskpart doesnt show that flash drive in the **disk list**